# Add/remove class from div's when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have one page web app with 5 link's navigation and 5 sections. The structure is this:

```
<div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home-section">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-section">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills-section">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ps-section">P.S.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="home-section">
        <div class="home-section--greeting">
            <p>Hi, I'm</p>
            <p>T. Green</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-section zoomOut">

    </div>
    <div class="skills-section zoomOut">

    </div>
    <div class="contact-section zoomOut">

    </div>
    <div class="ps-section zoomOut">

    </div>
```

Every section is behind the `home-section` on page load. The sections are stacked on top of eachother with `100vh` and `position absolute`. Also, every section EXCEPT the `home-section` has `zoomOut` class with `transform: scale(0.8)`.

What I want to do is the following: when a link from the `nav` is clicked, I want the corresponding section to zoom-in and the active section to zoom-out, meaning the `zoomOut` class should be removed and the new section will slowly fade in (I will tackle the `opacity` and all animations, don't worry).

I want to do this in pure Javascript so, no jQuery/framework comments and pointers, please.

Also, I assembled a little jsfiddle so you could go to straight experimenting, if you may: https://jsfiddle.net/h7wturbf/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Element#classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plain javascript sample, using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to catch and target links/sections

I added a `zoomIn` class to simplify how to toggle the sections

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.main-nav a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var divtarget = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
      document.querySelector('.zoomIn').classList.remove('zoomIn');
      document.querySelector('.' + divtarget).classList.add('zoomIn');
    })
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}
.zoomOut {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.zoomIn {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.home-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.home-section .home-section--greeting {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 62px;
  color: #005168;
}
.about-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.skills-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
.contact-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.ps-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-size: 21px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4F96AA;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #65AABD;
}
.main-nav ul li a.about:active ~ #about-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home-section">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about-section">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#skills-section">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#ps-section">P.S.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="home-section zoomOut zoomIn">
  <div class="home-section--greeting">
    <p>Hi, I'm</p>
    <p>T. Green</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="about-section zoomOut">

</div>
<div class="skills-section zoomOut">

</div>
<div class="contact-section zoomOut">

</div>
<div class="ps-section zoomOut">

</div>
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You should first bind onclick Event handler to those elements that can be clicked. Once the element is clicked, you could remove the class using :

```
this.classList.remove('class-name');
```